# Static analysis using Spotbugs in Jenkins from git hub project

Tags: jenkins, static-analysis, spotbugs

i am trying to do static analysis using spotbugs in jenkins from github project (multi module )
all module have different spotbugxml.xml file in target (it is not in main target folder ) and pom.xml
but when i am trying to static analysis , jenkins done it only for one module
so question is here how can we do static analysis(spotbugs ) for  all module
point:-
1)Do we have to merge all spotbugsxml.xml file ? if yes then how ?
2)or any other solution ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you can use a pattern.
2. For example `'**/spotbugsXml.xml'`